how to plot changes across maps on different dates
I am using map shapefile of the US.
Based on the map of 1900, I want to see what part changed their state in 1920? It should be a map of large whites and pits of blue that indicate the changes.
I am using sf package with ggplot. I have tried st_difference and st_sym_difference. But they don't seem to work.
Shapefiles are downloaded from
https://digital.newberry.org/ahcb/downloads/united_states.html
what I have done is
states <- st_read("/US_HistStateTerr_Gen01_Shapefile/US_HistStateTerr_Gen01.shp")

states <- states %>%
  rename_all(tolower) 

state_map_1900 <- states %>% filter(ymd(19000101) %within% interval(start_date, end_date))
state_map_1920 <- states %>% filter(ymd(19201231) %within% interval(start_date, end_date))
map_change <- st_difference(state_map_1900, state_map_1920)

ggplot() +
  # Baseline map (1900)
  geom_sf(data = state_map_1900, fill = "white", color = "black") +  
  # Highlight changes
  geom_sf(data = map_change, fill = 'blue', color = NA) +  
  labs(title = "Areas that Changed States", fill = "") +
  theme_minimal()

But the whole map just got to be blue. It cannot be right.
Can you help me out? Thank you.

You've plotted correctly, but there's an issue with your subsetting. First, the data you're using is extremely detailed. If a county line moved 1 inch, it's in there. The same data is in the two subsets (2319 rows are the same). This may show you how subtle the changes can be: ggplot() + geom_sf(data = state_map_1920[str_detect(state_map_1920$state_terr, "Oklahoma"), ], color = NA, fill = "lightblue", alpha = 1) + geom_sf(data = state_map_1900[state_map_1900$state_terr %in% c("Oklahoma Territory"), ], color ="black", fill = "white", alpha = 1) + theme_minimal()

If you first join those 1900 & 1920 subsets to generate an sf object with multiple geometry columns, you can get a pairwise st_sym_difference() or  st_difference() with purrr::map2() or mapply() :
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

# use GDAL virtual filesystems to fetch and extract shapes from online archive
vsi <- paste0(
  "/vsizip/vsicurl/",
  "https://digital.newberry.org/ahcb/downloads/gis/US_AtlasHCB_StateTerr_Gen01.zip",
  "/US_AtlasHCB_StateTerr_Gen01/US_HistStateTerr_Gen01_Shapefile"
)

# id-s can change, extract id prefix from id for joining
states <- 
  read_sf(vsi) |>  
  rename_with(tolower) |> 
  mutate(id_pref = str_split_i(id, "_", 1), .before = id) |> 
  select(id_num:end_date, area_sqmi, geometry)
print(states, n = 4)
#> Simple feature collection with 220 features and 8 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -179.1474 ymin: 18.91228 xmax: -66.94993 ymax: 71.38961
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 220 × 9
#>   id_num name              id_pref id    version start_date end_date   area_sqmi
#>    <int> <chr>             <chr>   <chr>   <int> <date>     <date>         <dbl>
#> 1      1 Alaska Department ak      ak_d…       1 1867-03-30 1884-05-16    575301
#> 2      2 Alaska District   ak      ak_d…       1 1884-05-17 1912-08-23    575301
#> 3      3 Alaska            ak      ak_s…       1 1959-01-03 2000-12-31    575301
#> 4      4 Alaska Territory  ak      ak_t…       1 1912-08-24 1959-01-02    575301
#> # ℹ 216 more rows
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: geometry <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>

# full join subsets by id prefix, as_tibble(y) as full_join of 2 sf objects would fail,
# resulting sf object is with 2 geometry columns (geometry.00, geometry.20);
# iterate through geometry pairs to get pair-wise differences as 3rd geometry column, 
# add area from (sym) diff
state_map_1900_1920 <- 
  full_join(
    states |>             filter(ymd(19000101) %within% interval(start_date, end_date)),
    as_tibble(states) |>  filter(ymd(19201231) %within% interval(start_date, end_date)),
    by = "id_pref", suffix = c(".00", ".20")) |> 
  mutate(geom_diff = map2(geometry.00, geometry.20, st_sym_difference) |> st_sfc(crs = st_crs(geometry.00)),
         diff_area = st_area(geom_diff) |> units::set_units(mi^2))

glimpse(state_map_1900_1920)
#> Rows: 52
#> Columns: 19
#> $ id_num.00     <int> 2, 7, 11, 17, 18, 20, 25, 27, 28, 39, 44, 46, 49, 51, 55…
#> $ name.00       <chr> "Alaska District", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "Arizona Terri…
#> $ id_pref       <chr> "ak", "al", "ar", "az", "ca", "co", "ct", "dc", "de", "f…
#> $ id.00         <chr> "ak_district", "al_state", "ar_state", "az_terr", "ca_st…
#> $ version.00    <int> 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2,…
#> $ start_date.00 <date> 1884-05-17, 1820-12-19, 1840-05-21, 1866-05-05, 1850-09…
#> $ end_date.00   <date> 1912-08-23, 2000-12-31, 2000-12-31, 1912-02-13, 1959-12…
#> $ area_sqmi.00  <dbl> 575301, 51656, 53179, 113999, 158097, 104093, 4975, 68, …
#> $ geometry.00   <MULTIPOLYGON [°]> MULTIPOLYGON (((-179.0575 5..., MULTIPOLYGO…
#> $ id_num.20     <int> 4, 7, 11, 15, 18, 20, 25, 27, 28, 39, 44, 48, 49, 51, 55…
#> $ name.20       <chr> "Alaska Territory", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "Arizona", "C…
#> $ id.20         <chr> "ak_terr", "al_state", "ar_state", "az_state", "ca_state…
#> $ version.20    <int> 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 2…
#> $ start_date.20 <date> 1912-08-24, 1820-12-19, 1840-05-21, 1912-02-14, 1850-09…
#> $ end_date.20   <date> 1959-01-02, 2000-12-31, 2000-12-31, 2000-12-31, 1959-12…
#> $ area_sqmi.20  <dbl> 575301, 51656, 53179, 113999, 158097, 104093, 4975, 68, …
#> $ geometry.20   <MULTIPOLYGON [°]> MULTIPOLYGON (((-179.0575 5..., MULTIPOLYGO…
#> $ geom_diff     <GEOMETRY [°]> GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EM…
#> $ diff_area     [mi^2] 0.0000 [mi^2], 0.0000 [mi^2], 0.0000 [mi^2], 0.0000 [mi…

Changes:
state_map_1900_1920 |> 
  filter(!st_is_empty(geom_diff)) |> 
  st_drop_geometry() |>
  select(id.00, name.00, end_date.00, id.20, name.20, area_sqmi.00, area_sqmi.20, diff_area)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 8
#>   id.00         name.00            end_date.00 id.20    name.20      area_sqmi.00 area_sqmi.20 diff_area
#>   <chr>         <chr>              <date>      <chr>    <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>    [mi^2]
#> 1 it_indianterr Indian Territory   1907-11-15  <NA>     <NA>                31075           NA  31074.  
#> 2 mi_state      Michigan           1908-12-31  mi_state Michigan            58121        58371    246.  
#> 3 ne_state      Nebraska           1902-11-03  ne_state Nebraska            77361        77353      7.56
#> 4 ok_terr       Oklahoma Territory 1907-11-15  ok_state Oklahoma            38824        69899  31074.  
#> 5 sd_state      South Dakota       1902-11-03  sd_state South Dakota        77107        77115      7.56

# aes(geometry = ...) to specify geometry colum
ggplot(state_map_1900_1920) +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry.00), fill = "white", color = "black", linewidth = .05) +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geom_diff),   fill = 'blue', color = "blue") +
  coord_sf(crs = 5070) +
  theme_minimal()


Created on 2024-09-23 with reprex v2.1.1
